Adding to travel history with trip between application and US visa interview
I plan to apply for a B1/B2 US Visa. However, I have travel plans to a different country between the application form filling and the interview. So, by the interview date, my application will be out of date and missing a country in the travel history.
Should I just list the travel history as of the day I am filing the application and securing an interview date?
The country I am visiting will stamp my passport, which the interviewer can see, so should say during the interview that I have been to an additional place during this while?
If it also matters, I have had a refusal from the US under 214b years back (8 or 9 years back). I am not sure if this can also have any impact.
PS: Having the interview before the trip is risky if I may not get the passport on time, and filling the application after this trip is also dicey for me due to many other travel plans.

What country will you be visiting? Unless it’s Syria, Afghanistan, Yemen, Iran, North Korea or the like, it probably won’t matter much…

@jcaron Don't just think of what'd be unhelpful: if OP was denied under 214b before, having positive travel history in the middle is helpful, as it establishes that OP knows how to travel and does leave countries on time, without causing issues while there.

@jcaron Na, not those countries but Egypt!

Don't mention it. There's a chance that your flights/trains/etc may be canceled or delayed. There's a chance that you might have a medical incident, a victim of a crime, etc. in this country and that you might need to stay longer. While the hope is that these won't happen, these would all lead to your travel history being not just out of date, but also incorrect.
Leave it out, and if it comes up during the visa interview, state that you did this trip between your form submission and your interview and that you didn't want to add it as you wanted to be safe for the reasons I stated.

Perfect, makes total sense. Thank you. One q additionally though, I dont recollect if there's a box with any notes or comments I can give while submitting. In case there's one, should I mention there, "I have a trip planned to XYZ but is not reflected in visited countries list as of filling the form but might be an additional country on the day of the interview" or something as a side note?

@trollster if there's such a box, then yes, do mention that you have a travel planned but will not add it as the dates are not final at the time of form submission. I don't see this hurting your chances, and it establishes honesty (if it comes up later you can point to it and say "I had declared this beforehand").
